# Delegate onclick event conflict in multiple pages with Framework7

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-framework-7

I’m using the last version of Framework7 (5.7).

I have this problem. I have some dynamic content in my pages, included inside the Dom with `$('.element').html()`.

In order to manage the `onclick()` event on this elements I use delegate in this way:

```
$(document).on(‘click’, ‘.favorite-icon’, function(event) {}
```

or

```
$(document).delegate(’.favorite-icon’, ‘click’, function(event) {}
```

The `onclick()` event works good with this method, but I have a problem.
Some of this elements exist in multiple pages. So if I change page in my app and click on those elements the `onclick()` event is triggered twice or more if I change multiple times page.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).undelegate('click').delegate(’.favorite-icon’, ‘click’, function(event) {}
```

It should eliminate all conflicts.